# Windows installer throws an error for unmodified MSI CAB

Tags: windows-installer

In MSI upgrade, if I don't include the unmodified MSI cab in the installset, windows installer throws this error during upgrade:

`Error 1334. The file '{FILE}.{GUID}' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file '{CABFILE}.cab'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.`

Note that, the specified cab in the error is NOT modified.

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by "include the unmodified MSI cab"... Have you modified an MSI and are trying to install from that? Is this a fresh/new install or an update? Please clarify and we'll be glad to help!

Comment: This is an update. Only few of the MSI data cabs contain the modified files in this update. So we are not including unmodified MSI data cabs in this update.

e.g.
<code>
Release 1 installset: MyProduct.msi, data1.cab, data2.cab

Release 2 installset: MyProduct.msi, data2.cab
</code>

We are not including data1.cab here as no file from it is modified.

Now the problem is, during upgrade installer is throwing the error 1334 as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The Windows Installer will look for all the cabinets. Make sure the files are in the right cabinets and the order in the cabinets matches the Sequence column in the File table.

Comment: "...the order in the cabinets matches the Sequence column in the File table"

How to determine "the order in the cabinets" ???